# NSFetchedResultsController - KVO, UITableView and a "Tree"

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, tree, key-value-observing

I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController to implement KVO for my UITableView (which is obvious). What I can't figure out is, how to use multiple Entities - sort of a tree structure - to be present(ed) simultaneously.

Here is my setup:

- Entity1

  - DisplayName
  - RelationToEntity2
- Entity2

  - DisplayName

Now I can fetch the data of either to be presented - so far so good. What I want is to have a one-sectioned TableView (like a flattened view) with the following structure:

- Entity1 (Entry 1)
- Entity2 (Entry 1)
- Entity2 (Entry 2)
- …
- Entity1 (Entry 2)
- …

Though it might look like a thing to be done via sections, it's not. Both Entities should be a UITableViewCells. Can someone please point me the right direction to flatten the without loosing the actual hierarchy.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it directly with an NSFetchedResultsController; you'll have to create an intermediate model, the characteristics of which will depend on how many items you have in your eventual table view. It's also not clear from your example how you go from your tree structure to your flattened view -- could you please provide something more complete?

Comment: The actual problem is how I get the flattened structure from the tree. My tableview does not know how many items there will be - this is all done by the NSFetchedResultsController.
I could create an intermediate model, but that is what I really do not want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to maintain your own 'flattened' datasource. Perhaps the following will work:

When `NSFetchedResultController` tells you a new `Entity1` has been inserted, you insert `Entity1` and its associated `Entity2`s into say, `_flattenedArray` so it looks like this:

`[<Entity1>, <related Entity2>, <related Entity2>...]`

Where you insert them is up to you - it pretty much comes down to:

1. construct a subarray containing the new `Entity1` and associated `Entity2` objects
2. decide where in `_flattenedArray` to insert the new subarray.
3. call `reloadData` or some other means to inform the `tableView` of the new data

When an `Entity1` object is removed, remove it and all subsequent `Entity2` objects until you encounter the end of `_flattenedArray` or run into another `Entity1` object. This assumes `Entity2` is never a "top level" object. If it is you will need to only remove those `Entity2` objects in the relation.

When an `Entity1` object gains or loses an `Entity2` object, you can first delete the `Entity1` object from `_flattenedArray` then reinserting it. If this is too efficient, do a merge instead.

Comment: This sounds reasonable and is one of the things I thought of. What about the memory footprint? I'll always have double data in my memory, right? A solution to this though could be to only fetch the Entities bare hull.

Comment: You won't - the NSArray stores references to objects, not copies of objects. If they are coming from CoreData, they are NSManagedObjects which means they might not even be in memory until you access its attributes or some other operation that faults them into memory.

Comment: I made it that way and it seems to work fine. Caveat is that I'll at some point have to take care of re-populating the plain list when KVO updates the data, and that is not perfectly done yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the situation to use entity inheritance. When fetching a parent abstract entity with a fetched results controller all of the child entities can be displayed by the table. Use a section order property to display the sections in the order you prefer. And use a second sort property to order within the sections. The Notes app does this by fetching an abstract Container entity and displays Accounts and Folders which are child entities. It sections by Account and the first folder "All iCloud" cell is actually an Account. Folders have a relation to an account even though they are equals in the entity inheritance tree.